# Laravel URL to file in storage does not work in browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, storage

I have this filesystem config for my folder:

```
'apks' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public/apks'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage/apks',
    'visibility' => 'public',
]
```

Here are app apks saved.

I need to return the URL to the file (NOT THE FILE ITSELF).

The android APK manager will then download and install the file by using the URL.

The URL is created by calling:

```
Storage::disk('apks')->url($result->filename)
```

It works, the URL looks like this:

```
https://www.example.com/storage/apks/app-debug.apk
```

BUT it can not download the file.

**Also if I use this URL in the browser I get a 404 error**

I would have expected that the file will be downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate a symlink for access publicly from the storage folder.

Here you can able to run below command in the composer:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Now you can access:

```
https://www.example.com/storage/apks/yourfile.xyz
```

Comment: Will it work for all files in the folder or only 1 file? I always thought it works only for one

Comment: Okay. I have just created a folder in public (where css and js folders are) and it works this way.